# Duda con Punteros a arreglos de Variables de Estructura

Tags: c, punteros, struct

Mi duda es, ¿Porqué el puntero `const wDeck`, que está como parámetro en las funciones `fillDeck`, `shuffle` y `deal`, no tiene corchetes al final (es decir, no es un puntero a un arreglo a diferencia de los otros parámetros)?

Si se supone que ese puntero apunta al arreglo de variables de estructura `Card`, ¿Porqué al ponerle corchetes a los parámetros wDeck, el programa presenta errores?
Y al no hacerlo, ¿El programa corre perfectamente?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Definition of the structure 'card' */
struct card
{
    const char *face;
    const char *suit;
}; /* End of the definition of the structure 'card'. */

typedef struct card Card;

void fillDeck(Card *const wDeck, const char *wFace[], const char *wSuit[]);
void shuffle(Card *const wDeck);
void deal(const Card *const wDeck);

int main()
{
    Card deck[52];

    /* Initialize the arrays of pointers */
    const char *face[] = {"Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    const char *suit[] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};

    srand(time(NULL));

    fillDeck(deck, face, suit);
    shuffle(deck);
    deal(deck);

    getch();
    return 0;
}

/* Place strings into Card structures. */
void fillDeck(Card *const wDeck, const char *wFace[], const char *wSuit[])
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<=51; i++)
    {
        wDeck[i].face = wFace[i % 13];
        wDeck[i].suit = wSuit[i / 13];
    }
}

void shuffle(Card *const wDeck)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    Card temp;

    for(i=0; i<=51; i++)
    {
        j = rand() % 2;
        temp = wDeck[i];
        wDeck[i] = wDeck[j];
        wDeck[j] = temp;
    }
}

void deal(const Card *const wDeck)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<=51; i++)
    {
        printf("%5s of %-8s%s", wDeck[i].face, wDeck[i].suit, (i + 1) % 4 ? " " : "\n");

    }
}
```

Comment: Tal vez deberías explicar mejor el tema de los corchetes con un par de ejemplos (el correcto y el que te da error)

Answer (score 1):

En C, `TYPE[]` y `TYPE*` con básicamente *equivalentes* e *intercambiables*, como te indica claramente eferion en su respuesta.

Sin embargo, tu inquietud proviede de **otro detalle**, indirectamente relacionado con lo anterior, pero distinto. En este código

```
void fillDeck( Card *const wDeck, const char *wFace[], const char *wSuit[] );
```

`wFace` y `sWuit` son `const char *`, es decir, son punteros **a datos constantes**; puedes modificar el propio puntero, pero **no puedes modificar el dato apuntado**. La expresión `*wFace = XXX` sería **errónea**, mientras que la expresión `wFace = XXX` sería **correcta**.

`wDeck`, por otra parte, es un **puntero constante** a un dato. Fíjate en la posición del `const`, que no es la misma que en los anteriores. Eso quiere decir que **Puedes** modificar el dato, haciendo, por ejemplo, `*wDeck = XXX`; lo que **no puedes hacer** es **modificar el puntero en sí**.

Ahora, si tú añades los corchetes

```
Card *const wDeck[]
```

Debido a lo que dijimos sobre que los punteros son intercambiables con los *arreglos*, en realidad, el compilador ve esto:

```
Card *const Card *wDeck
```

Lo cual es un tipo **completamente distinto** al original, y que no concuerda con al valor que intentas usar, que sigues tomando de la variable `Card deck[52]`, y cuyo tipo, por tanto, es `Card *`.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Lo he entendido perfectamente ...

Answer (score 0):

En C, un puntero simple no es más que una variable que almacena una posición de memoria:

```
int* puntero;
```

Cuando queremos que un puntero almacene una colección de elementos entonces estamos ante un arreglo unidimensional o un vector. Si el número de elementos no es excesivamente grande podemos optar por crearlo en la pila:

```
int vector[100];
```

Con la declaración anterior lo que conseguimos es reservar espacio para 100 elementos de tipo `int`. Los diferentes elementos van a estar en posiciones consecutivas de la memoria:

```
elem1 | elem2 | elem3 | ... | elem100
```

Debido a esta característica el compilador no tiene la necesidad de *recordar* la posición de cada elemento. Le basta con saber la posición del primer elemento y aplicar un desplazamiento a partir de dicha posición. Es por esto que un *vector* es equiparable a un puntero simple:

```
int vector[100];

int *puntero = vector; // ok
```

Y, por extensión, cuando llamamos a una función que admite punteros simples le dará igual si dicho puntero apunta a un único elemento o a una colección de los mismos:

```
void func(int*);

int vector[100];
int *puntero = vector;

func(vector);  // ok
func(puntero); // ok
```

En cuanto al uso de los corchetes te aconsejaría explicar mejor a qué te refieres... un ejemplo de ambos casos de uso (con error y sin error).

Comment: Tu explicación sobre la relación `punteros` <-> `arreglos` es **muy buena** y **fácil de entender**. ¿ wiki de comunidad ? ¿ o pregunta aparte, tipo `¿ cual es la relación entre los punteros y los arreglos en C / C++ ?` ?